# regex + find a value and return different strings based on the different values

Tags: regex

I have a [regex query here](https://regex101.com/r/oE2nE5/1) and what I want to do is return a diferent strings based on what it finds.

I am interested in the digits after K' 

if the number begins with 81 return foo and not 81 e.g. foo
if the number begins with 916 return bar and not 916 e.g. bar

sample data:

```
K'813456
K'8134567

K'9164567
K'916456789
```

Can this be done and if so how?

**EDIT1**

This is a further regex example to illustrate what I am trying to do(for my reference if anything)

https://regex101.com/r/jO8zZ5/2

Comment: What language do you want to use to achieve that?

Comment: I am looking to use it in splunk but I would be happy if I could achieve it on regex101 initially?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you can't solve that with an `if ... else ...` statement, but you could do this on a regex level by a 2-step approach:

1. Substitution: `s/K'81/K'foo/g` and `s/K'916/K'bar/g` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO2aF4/1)
2. Extraction: `K'([a-z]+)` whereas `$1` will contain the string [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vR4vR0/2)

--
Edit: Demo links added

Comment: can I do that on regex101 for now?

Comment: maybe i am not clear, my example finds 81 and returns 81, finds 916 and returns 916, I want to find 81 and return foo, find 916 and return bar. if I am not mistake your examples are finding 81 and replacing it with foo? I do not want to replace I want to return a value which is different to the one I find. Dese that make sense?

Comment: I've understood that. I don't think, that's possible with a single regex. That's why I suggested to use two regexes if you don't want to differentiate it within your source. Please note, that I've added two demo links to my answer: the first demo replaces `81` with `foo` and the second demo takes the output of the first as input and extracts the letters after `K'`, which will give you the `foo`.

Comment: To specify myself: you'll need one regex for each number-string-replacement.